# How to turn off Motion Controller line pointer

Tags: pointers, controller, mrtk

That's it, I'll step on my pride!

I'm using MRTK v2 and working fine except that at some point I want to turn off the line extending from the Motion Controller to the object and that provides input. After looking around and trying to find it in the MRTK documentation (it's gotta be easy, right?), I'm still banging my head on the wall and it's starting to hurt....

The MRTK documentation explains quite well how to configure it here:

https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_release/Documentation/Input/Pointers.md

But I'm looking to do this in script, enabling and disabling it as I need it in my application.

Any clue how to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, perhaps the terminology you are using is incorrect. Are you trying to disable the line pointer (this is represented by DefaultControllerPointer in the pointer profile), or the mediator? The mediator is a component that enables and disables other pointers like the DefaultControllerPointer and the SpherePointer based on the state of the system.

Comment: You are right Julia, I may not understand very well the terminology yet and what I mean is the line pointer that extends from the motion controller. I wish there was a clear tutorial/script/instructions to the  MRTK scripting, but since I'm only allowed to ask one question here, let's go with the line pointer. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi Francois I started working on an answer for you this weekend but not quite done because I got distracted by a P0 issue. I think the best way to do this would be to extend / modify the DefaultPointerMediator class and expose a reference to it from FocusProvider. I'm working on an answer for you, please expect one today or tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks so much Julia!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered my own question. Simple:

PointerUtils.SetMotionControllerRayPointerBehavior(PointerBehavior.AlwaysOff);

See documentation here: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_release/Documentation/Input/Pointers.md

Answer (score 0):

Great question! Here's one way to do this that has worked for me. You can see my solution at this repository: https://github.com/julenka/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/so/linepointer_off. Open the scene `Assets/TurnOffLinePointerTest.unity` and then use hand simulation to press the buttons. The code to turn the pointers on/off is in `Assets/PointerConfigurationExample.cs`.

Note: the reason you need to use this approach of modifying the mediator instead of directly setting `myPointer.IsActive = false` is because the default mediator overwrites these values every frame. Luckily, you can customize this behavior.

### Step 1: Update MRTK a bit so that PointerMediator can be accessed

Apply the changes [from this commit](https://github.com/julenka/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/commit/c2b6dc55b579370a44b1887e0db3ea0d05a0dd0f) to your MRTK clone. This change updates the FocusProvider in MRTK to make the PointerMediator publicly accessible, and makes the DefaultPointerMediator extensible by updating fields to be protected instead of private, and making methods virtual. See [this pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/4698) that implements this change directly into MRTK.

### Step 2: Create a custom PointerMediator that will turn off far pointers

Create a custom Pointer Mediator like [the one from this commit](https://github.com/julenka/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/commit/cc631f603d14720ac31dbc37100bdcc042aede14).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;

public class CustomPointerMediator : DefaultPointerMediator
{
    public bool FarPointersDisabled {get; set;}

    public override void UpdatePointers()
    {
        base.UpdatePointers();
        if (FarPointersDisabled)
        {
            foreach(var pointer in farInteractPointers)
            {
                pointer.IsActive = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this mediator extends `DefaultPointerMediator` so it adapts almost all the default mediator logic. Make sure you have fully applied the changes [from the first commit](https://github.com/julenka/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/commit/c2b6dc55b579370a44b1887e0db3ea0d05a0dd0f) otherwise you will not be able to extend `DefaultPointerMediator`.

#### Step 3: Tell MRTK to use your custom pointer mediator

In your pointer profile, configure MRTK to use the custom pointer mediator instead of the default pointer mediator. Notice in the picture that I've created a custom pointer profile as part of a custom input system (don't modify the default profile otherwise your changes might get overwritten when you update MRTK).

[image]

#### Step 4: Component that uses custom mediator to turn line pointers on / off

You can now write your component which will use your custom mediator to turn the line pointers on and off.

```
public class PointerConfigurationExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    /* Turns off all far interaction pointers */
    public void TurnOffFarPointers()
    {
        Debug.Log("Line pointers off");
        SetFarPointersDisabled(true);
    }

    public void TurnOnFarPointers()
    {
        Debug.Log("Line pointers on");
        SetFarPointersDisabled(false);
    }

    private void SetFarPointersDisabled(bool isDisabled)
    {
        FocusProvider focusProvider = (FocusProvider) MixedRealityToolkit.InputSystem.FocusProvider;
        if (focusProvider != null)
        {
            foreach(var mediator in focusProvider.PointerMediators)
            {
                // Note: you could check here to make sure you only disable pointers for hands
                CustomPointerMediator myMediator = (CustomPointerMediator) (mediator.Value);
                if (myMediator != null)
                {
                    myMediator.FarPointersDisabled = isDisabled;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Julia. I know you spent a lot of time on this! Which makes me wonder why those who conceived the MRTK made this operation so complicated when it's a very basic function, equivalent to turning off the mouse cursor or replacing it programmatically... but thank you again, I've been looking for so long how to do this and I'm far from a newbie programmer! Makes me feel less ashamed I guess...

Comment: I'm getting an error compiling this: Assets\MixedRealityToolkit-Unity-mrtk_release\Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Services\InputSystem\FocusProvider.cs(451,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GazePointerVisibilityStateMachine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Hi, yes, that's from a class that's in the latest mrtk_development but probably not something you have yet. Make sure to copy just the changed outlined in my commit (https://github.com/julenka/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/commit/c2b6dc55b579370a44b1887e0db3ea0d05a0dd0f), not the whole file.

Comment: Fantastic! Working great! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi Julia, since I have upgraded to MRTK version 2.3, this does not work. The line " FocusProvider focusProvider = (FocusProvider) MixedRealityToolkit.InputSystem.FocusProvider;" gives me an Invalid Type Cast error…. Any hints?

Comment: Looks like you answered it above :-)